# If the user enters the incorrect credentials, display a modal with an error

Tags: php, html, laravel

When the user enters one or more wrong credentials, a modal appears. The problem is that I don't know how I can make this connection from controller to view. Would an ajax be needed, probably?

Controller:

```
      public function login()
  {
    return view('login');
  }

  public function logar(Request $req)
  {
    $data = $req->all();
    $verify = Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']]);
    $this->validate($req, [
      'email' => [
        'required',
        'email',
      ]
    ]);
    if ($verify) {
      return redirect()->route('shop.index');
    }
    return redirect()->route('shop.login');
  }
```

View:

```
                <form class="login-form needs-validation" method="POST" action="{{ route('loja.logar') }}" novalidate>
                    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control w-50 mx-auto my-0 py-4" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control w-50 mx-auto my-0 py-4" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2 py-3 px-4">Enviar</button>
                </form>

               <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Error</h5>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                         Login or password incorrect! Try again.
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: if i understand you clearly, are you checking the error here if ($verify) {
      return redirect()->route('shop.index');
    }
    return redirect()->route('shop.login');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two actually different cases, **validation** and **verification**. If the **verification error message** uses modal, does the **validation error message** use it too?

#### NO (Short Answer)

```php
if ($verify) {
    return redirect()->route('shop.index');
}

return redirect()->route('shop.login', ['status' => 'error']);
```

```
@if(request()->input('status') == 'error')
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Error</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Login or password incorrect! Try again.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

```
@if(request()->input('status') == 'error')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal1").modal('show');
</script>
@endif
```

---

#### YES (Long Answer)

I don't know what `$this->validate` does, but I assume it's the same thing as `validate` method provided by the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object.

If you look at the default `LoginController`, you will find that the verification error message is the same as validation, using:

```php
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
]);
```

That means, you will have one action for both. But in your case, you separate them.

```
/******** VALIDATION ********/
// if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and 
// the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user.
$input = $req->validate($req, [
    'email'    => ['required', 'email'],
    'password' => ['required'],
]);

/******** VERIFICATION ********/
$verify = Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']]);

if ($verify) {
    return redirect()->route('shop.index');
}

// return redirect()->route('shop.login', ['status' => 'error']);
// or 
return redirect()->route('shop.login')
    ->with('status-verification', 'Login or password incorrect! Try again.');
```

```
@if($errors->any())
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-validation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Error Validation</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif

@if(session('status-verification'))
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-verification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Error</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ session('status-verification') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if($errors->any())
        $("#modal-validation").modal('show');
    @endif

    @if(session('status-verification'))
        $("#modal-verification").modal('show');
    @endif
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I used the second method which, despite being longer, was more worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script where you want to call the modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#modal1").modal();
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#modal1").modal('show');
</script>
```

Requires bootstrap and jquery libraries to work.

Comment: Yes. I want the modal to appear if the user enters the wrong credentials. Where should I place the javascript code? Directly on the Controller?

Comment: But, in that case in first reload also, the modal will be showing... if I am not wrong!!! And @FelipeMoreira Why are you not using any template??

Comment: Are you talking about the blade template? If so, I don't know why or why to apply it.

Comment: @FelipeMoreira Template, they are very important to send data from views and to template in the form of dictionary ... Then you can retrieve it easily... In your problem... if you have used template...

Comment: Use exceptions and handle it in your controller. It should work fine, assuming you get what I'm putting across.

Comment: I don't know how to explain... but I think you should do research in templates to make your projects simpler, clear and optimized... You are right that you could but as project becomes bigger... You will need it. I do more of django than laravel... but it is there in laravel tooo... I would strongly suggest you to learn the use of template [laravel template](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade)...

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to use template, I think you should use ajax to retrive validation..
**But I think you should definately use templates to make it simpler**... Obviously, ajax can handle it, but I don't think ajax is going to be right solution for these kind of problems. **Sorry, as I am saying so much about template, but i found it dissapointing seeing you not using templates**
[Visit blade template](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) and 
[Visit twig template](https://twig.symfony.com/)